# Jemalloc functions not declared in this scope

Tags: g++, jemalloc

I installed the jemalloc library on my ubuntu machine by

```
sudo apt-get install libjemalloc-dev
```

Now, I can't compile a simple code that uses the jemalloc library:

```
#include <jemalloc/jemalloc.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    void* ptr = je_malloc(16);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile  it by `g++ -ljemalloc example.cpp`.

The error I get is

```
example.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
example.cpp:5:24: error: ‘ je_malloc’ was not declared in this scope
  void* ptr = je_malloc(16);
```

I even tried installing jemalloc using its source file and changed my header to `"jemalloc/jemalloc.h"` (instead of `<..>`), and linked to it using `g++ -L./jemalloc/lib example.cpp`, but it didn't help.

Comment: As long as you use `-ljemalloc` then just call `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I look at the [documentation](http://jemalloc.net/jemalloc.3.html) there is no function `je_malloc`, so the error is normal

Replace `je_malloc` by `malloc`

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late but it may be useful for someone else. If you want to use the `je_` prefixed version of the API you have to add `--with-jemalloc-prefix=je_` option when compiling the library (in this case when running configure script).